# codeblocks main page won't load?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

code:

```
// -*- C++ -*- forwarding header.

// Copyright (C) 1997-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
// permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
// 3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
// a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
// see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/** @file include/cwchar
 *  This is a Standard C++ Library file.  You should @c \#include this file
 *  in your programs, rather than any of the @a *.h implementation files.
 *
 *  This is the C++ version of the Standard C Library header @c wchar.h,
 *  and its contents are (mostly) the same as that header, but are all
 *  contained in the namespace @c std (except for names which are defined
 *  as macros in C).
 */

//
// ISO C++ 14882: 21.4
//

#pragma GCC system_header

#include <bits/c++config.h>

#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WCHAR_H
#include <wchar.h>
#endif

#ifndef _GLIBCXX_CWCHAR
#define _GLIBCXX_CWCHAR 1

// Need to do a bit of trickery here with mbstate_t as char_traits
// assumes it is in wchar.h, regardless of wchar_t specializations.
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_MBSTATE_T
extern "C"
{
  typedef struct
  {
    int __fill[6];
  } mbstate_t;
}
#endif

namespace std
{
  using ::mbstate_t;
} // namespace std

// Get rid of those macros defined in <wchar.h> in lieu of real functions.
#undef btowc
#undef fgetwc
#undef fgetws
#undef fputwc
#undef fputws
#undef fwide
#undef fwprintf
#undef fwscanf
#undef getwc
#undef getwchar
#undef mbrlen
#undef mbrtowc
#undef mbsinit
#undef mbsrtowcs
#undef putwc
#undef putwchar
#undef swprintf
#undef swscanf
#undef ungetwc
#undef vfwprintf
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VFWSCANF
# undef vfwscanf
#endif
#undef vswprintf
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VSWSCANF
# undef vswscanf
#endif
#undef vwprintf
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VWSCANF
# undef vwscanf
#endif
#undef wcrtomb
#undef wcscat
#undef wcschr
#undef wcscmp
#undef wcscoll
#undef wcscpy
#undef wcscspn
#undef wcsftime
#undef wcslen
#undef wcsncat
#undef wcsncmp
#undef wcsncpy
#undef wcspbrk
#undef wcsrchr
#undef wcsrtombs
#undef wcsspn
#undef wcsstr
#undef wcstod
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WCSTOF
# undef wcstof
#endif
#undef wcstok
#undef wcstol
#undef wcstoul
#undef wcsxfrm
#undef wctob
#undef wmemchr
#undef wmemcmp
#undef wmemcpy
#undef wmemmove
#undef wmemset
#undef wprintf
#undef wscanf

#if _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T

namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

  using ::wint_t;
using ::vfwscanf;
  using ::btowc;
  using ::fgetwc;
  using ::fgetws;
  using ::fputwc;
  using ::fputws;
  using ::fwide;
  using ::fwprintf;
  using ::fwscanf;
  using ::getwc;
  using ::getwchar;
  using ::mbrlen;
  using ::mbrtowc;
  using ::mbsinit;
  using ::mbsrtowcs;
  using ::putwc;
  using ::putwchar;
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF
  using ::swprintf;
#endif
  using ::swscanf;
  using ::ungetwc;
  using ::vfwprintf;
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WFWSCANF;
if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VFWSCANF
using ::vfwscanf;
#endif
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF
  using ::vswprintf;
#endif
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VSWSCANF
  using ::vswscanf;
#endif
  using ::vwprintf;
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VWSCANF
  using ::vwscanf;
#endif
  using ::wcrtomb;
  using ::wcscat;
  using ::wcscmp;
  using ::wcscoll;
  using ::wcscpy;
  using ::wcscspn;
  using ::wcsftime;
  using ::wcslen;
  using ::wcsncat;
  using ::wcsncmp;
  using ::wcsncpy;
  using ::wcsrtombs;
  using ::wcsspn;
  using ::wcstod;
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WCSTOF
  using ::wcstof;
#endif
  using ::wcstok;
  using ::wcstol;
  using ::wcstoul;
  using ::wcsxfrm;
  using ::wctob;
  using ::wmemcmp;
  using ::wmemcpy;
  using ::wmemmove;
  using ::wmemset;
  using ::wprintf;
  using ::wscanf;
  using ::wcschr;
  using ::wcspbrk;
  using ::wcsrchr;
  using ::wcsstr;
  using ::wmemchr;

#ifndef __CORRECT_ISO_CPP_WCHAR_H_PROTO
  inline wchar_t*
  wcschr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c)
  { return wcschr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }

  inline wchar_t*
  wcspbrk(wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2)
  { return wcspbrk(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__s1), __s2); }

  inline wchar_t*
  wcsrchr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c)
  { return wcsrchr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c); }

  inline wchar_t*
  wcsstr(wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2)
  { return wcsstr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__s1), __s2); }

  inline wchar_t*
  wmemchr(wchar_t* __p, wchar_t __c, size_t __n)
  { return wmemchr(const_cast<const wchar_t*>(__p), __c, __n); }
#endif

_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION
} // namespace

#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_WCHAR

#undef wcstold
#undef wcstoll
#undef wcstoull

namespace __gnu_cxx
{
#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CHECK || _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_DYNAMIC
  extern "C" long double
    (wcstold)(const wchar_t * __restrict, wchar_t ** __restrict) throw ();
#endif
#if !_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_DYNAMIC
  using ::wcstold;
#endif
#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_LONG_LONG_CHECK || _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_LONG_LONG_DYNAMIC
  extern "C" long long int
    (wcstoll)(const wchar_t * __restrict, wchar_t ** __restrict, int) throw ();
  extern "C" unsigned long long int
    (wcstoull)(const wchar_t * __restrict, wchar_t ** __restrict, int) throw ();
#endif
#if !_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_LONG_LONG_DYNAMIC
  using ::wcstoll;
  using ::wcstoull;
#endif
} // namespace __gnu_cxx

namespace std
{
  using ::__gnu_cxx::wcstold;
  using ::__gnu_cxx::wcstoll;
  using ::__gnu_cxx::wcstoull;
} // namespace

#endif

#endif //_GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T

namespace std
{
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WCSTOF
  using std::wcstof;
#endif
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VFWSCANF
  using std::vfwscanf;
#endif
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VSWSCANF
  using std::vswscanf;
#endif
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VWSCANF
  using std::vwscanf;
#endif

#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_WCHAR
  using std::wcstold;
  using std::wcstoll;
  using std::wcstoull;
#endif
} // namespace

#endif // _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T

#endif // C++11
```

error:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cwchar|164|error: expected unqualified-id before 'if'|

This is just trying to build and run the "hello world" start-up page, do not know what to do, fixed some mistakes with debugger, but this is just a pain and out of my depth of knowledge, never had this before

Answer (score 0):

Line 164 is the one indicated here:

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WFWSCANF;
if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VFWSCANF // this one
using ::vfwscanf;
#endif
```

It seems you have accidentally removed the `#` in front of the `if` there.
You should mark  the entire tree read-only using file permissions to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason, two erroneous lines have made their way to your compiler's cwchar file.

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WFWSCANF; // This looks erroneous
if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VFWSCANF       // Should be preprocessor if (#if)
using ::vfwscanf;
#endif
```

I downloaded and checked the `gcc-c++-6.3.0-1-mingw32` cwchar file, and surely it does not include that erroneous line:

```
#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_VFWSCANF
  using ::vfwscanf;
#endif
```

There wasn't enough `#endif`s for the `#ifndef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_WFWSCANF;` to be valid. Also, your copy pasted code seems to be missing an `#endif` from the very end:

```
#endif // _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T

#endif // C++11

#endif
```

For why the the error was generated, if the `_GLIBCXX_HAVE_VFWSCANF` was defined, the non-preprocessor `if` statement would expand like this:

```
if 1
using ::vfwscanf;
#endif
```

Maybe while looking at the compiler errors with your IDE you accidentally did some backspacing, cutting or copy pasting, or maybe your installation of mingw is somehow faulty? Hard to guess.

Either way, I would just remove the erroneous line and add the `#endif` to the end, if it was missing. If more errors show up in the compiler's files, I would consider reinstalling mingw.

Comment: How can I do that? Reinstall MinGW. Even more erroros showed up, youtube doesn;t give a clear answer on how to do that

Comment: And I do not know how it could have been corrupted(mingw), codeblocks came straight from the orginal website

Comment: MinGW provides an automated installer. Instructions for it are here: [Getting Started | MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/getting_started), see _Graphical User Interface Installer_. It should also detect previous installations and be able to remove them.